# I can connect to WiFi but all websites refuse to connect

Tags: connection-issues

I have a device running Android version 5.0.2 that connects to our WiFi network, but browsing to any website using Chrome displays a page with:

> The site can't be reached

and

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This device used to connect without a problem

I also have a second device running Android version 4.2.2 that still connects to the same network without any problems.

How can I troubleshoot the first device?

Comment: I'd go for some [Network Diagnosis](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis) app and check whether you can ping the sites affected, if the routing is OK, plus compare the settings with the ones on the working device (gateway, name servers). [Fing Network Tools](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing) is a good "Allround Toolbox" for that kind of stuff. Well rated, available for free – give it a try and please report back!

Comment: try checking the date and time of your device

Comment: @Izzy I installed Fing Network on both devices and they can both successfully ping google.co.uk. So, some higher level problem...any suggestions?

Comment: If there is *WPS* button or *reset* do that after clearing device Passwords and reconnect. I don't know if it will help but the suggestion is on the nature of trying to start afresh. Also clear the browser cache or use another browser to see if it's working

Comment: @KamalShetty has a point here: if those pages use HTTPS, and date/time on your device are "too far off", that could be an issue – as your "mis-timed device" thinks certificates are either not yet or no longer valid. To test that out, go to *Settings › Date & Time* and check what's shown there. Temporarily switch it to manual, and enter the current date/time – then try calling up those pages again. As your `ping` succeeded, your network obviously is OK – if the IP of the pinged server is correct (note: you could `ping 127.0.0.1`, but there wouldn't be a web server to respond :)

Comment: @Izzy tried everyone's suggestions. Nothing working...

Comment: Have you checked if the IP address `ping` receives responses from is the same from both devices, and really belongs to the host name you've pinged? Have you compered the traceroutes? This is just to rule out the possibility your DNS etc. got somehow "hijacked" (malware might have modified the system, for example). Also, Fing offers a service discovery so you could see whether e.g. `www.google.com` offers HTTP/HTTPS at all. If that all looks fine, and you've tried different browsers, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Izzy Ok, tried all of that, but no luck. So I did a hard reset and we're up and running again. Unfortunately I lost a small amount of data. Many thanks

Comment: With a [hard reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-reset/info) you shouldn't lose much. Guess you've rather done a [factory-reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) – last resort, and admittedly the only remaining option I can think of. If you have a little time, it would be a good idea to sum up what you've tried (and failed, and how), plus the "last resort", in an answer (which you then later "accept") – and we cleanup the comments here?

Comment: Correct. Followed instructions from here - http://www.hardreset.info/devices/asus/asus-z300c-zenpad-10/

Answer (score 0):

Try using a VPN, I recommend Thunder VPN if you are an Android user.

So far, this is the only solution that I thought of and that is what worked for me, but there are also other VPNs.

Answer (score 0):

This might happen due to some misconfiguration in settings.
You can try these tweaks to troubleshoot this error

1. open wifi networks, hold on the connected network, FORGET this and then again connect to the network
2. Try to change the SSID of the wifi
3. Try to make wifi OPEN( no password) and then try again to connect to the network
4. Also, check wifi-configuration on your router and make sure this device is not blacklisted.

Thanks.